# Connect to windows sever hosted on vmware using Remote Desktop

Tags: windows-server-2008, remote-desktop

I just installed windows sever 2008 on vmware, and I want to connect to it using Remote Desktop in my windows 8.1.

I configured the network interface as NAT, and I tried to access the Windows server using its IP :

[image]

But I got this message :

[image]

How can I solve this ?

Comment: Make sure that your network interface is up. Try to ping the ip in the first picture. In addition to that, please check if the remote desktop service is enabled on your virtual server. Try `nmap -PN -sS -p 3389 ip_of_vserver`, but try this from the vserver itself, too.

Comment: There's VMware Network Adapter on your host os. Is its ip set as 192.168.177.2? And try [this](https://pubs.vmware.com/horizon-61-view/index.jsp#com.vmware.horizon-view.desktops.doc/GUID-9AF9E21E-E313-4B65-B7D8-6AE3190641D6.html) to configure remote desktop in guest win server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid question, but did you enable Remote Desktop?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- Join machine to the domain
- Make sure that remote desktop is enabled and that you have
  permissions that allow you to connect.
- Can you ping the machine?
- Can you ping the machine using IP or its name?